# Spring project not creating spring-config.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have read some tutorials about using spring, and I've seen they speak about "spring-config.xml", but when I create a project I don't have that file, I have "application-config.xml", are they the same? Is the former the updated version of the latter? I am using Eclipse as IDE

Comment: Yes, they are the same; the name is not important. Just remember to use your application-config.xml where tutorials refers to spring-config.xml  
And enjoy learning Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Context only defines the concept of creating a Spring configuration where you will define spring components (beans, services, etc)

The XML itself can be named whatever you want, but in the web.xml file, you have to pass the xml name you choose to the spring context listener

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/thisXMLhaTheBestNameEver.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: But I have seen that there is a file called "context.xml" and there are those others two. Or are you saying context is related to one of those 2? Could you tell me what does it have to do with spring-config.xml and application-config.xml? Sorry I am a bit confused.

Comment: Basically, the file is an Spring configuration independent of the name. What I mean is that the file is called context.xml because of convention, so that when you see a xml file called context or somewhat (like applicationContext, springContext, etc), you can have an idea of what this xml is. The name you use is a thing of convenience. Is has more meaning to name it "context" or "springContext", than calling it "myfile.xml".